# How can I load a mysqldump .sql file to a MySQL database in Windows Vista

Tags: windows, mysql

I'm trying to move a MySQL database from a Linux machine to one running Windows Vista.

Using mysqldump, I've obtained a `.sql` file, which I have moved to the Windows machine.  Whats next?

If I were moving to another Linux machine, one could do this sort of thing:

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < dumpfile.sql
```

Does anyone know of an analogous invocation that works from the Windows command line?  Or are there tools to accomplish this?

When I try this type of command from the Windows command line, I get:

```
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I've also tried:

```
mysql>  source C:\Stuff\dumpfile.sql
```

That gave:

```
Failed to open file 'C:\Stuff\dumpfile.sql', error: 2
```

Comment: I think the default install path for the MySQL executable in windows is C:\Program Files\MySQL\bin, or something like that.  If you need to find it, do a search of your hard drive for MySQL.exe

Comment: That's it, I overlooked the \bin subdirectory in my search.  Thanks for your patience.  Done.

Comment: +1 for `mysql -u username -p databasename < dumpfile.sql`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This same type of command should work in windows as well as Linux.  Have you tried running this command? What type of error messages are you getting.

I just tested on my local machine with MySQL on Windows XP.  The only reason I could see this not working, is that MySQL isn't on your path.  If it isn't in your path, you need to specify the whole path of the MYSQL executable, or run it from the directory it's stored in.  You could also add the executable to the path if you plan to use the MySQL executable on a regular basis.

Comment: I'm sure I seem like a real rube, but I can't find my MySQL executable.  Any idea?

Answer (score 13):

See [this comment by Jeff Zohrab](https://web.archive.org/web/20130330172729/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/batch-commands.html#c6948) on the MySQL documentation:

For windows users, use forward slashes for the path delimiters. You also don't need to enclose the path to the file in quotes. E.g., the following works:

```
mysql> source C:/Documents and Settings/My name here/My Documents/script.sql;
```

Just in case, for Linux:

```
mysql> source /path/to/script.sql;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you get an 'error 2' is because the comand is been executed, so it's not because MysQL is not been found.

The error 2 is because you should use this path: `'C:/Stuff/dumpfile.sql'` instead of `'C:\Stuff\dumpfile.sql'`

You could also try `'C:\\Stuff\\dumpfile.sql'`, but the unix like path it's the way to go.

But the easiest way is this:

If the .sql file is in c:\temp, and the MySQL is installed in the default location:

```
C:\temp>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -p -h localhost myDatabase < myDatabaseDump.sql
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind doing it interactively, you can use the `source` command in the mysql shell, followed by the file name. Otherwise, I believe that Kibbee is right about pipes working in `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an environment variable in Windows XP, tested and confirmed for Vista, through setx.exe, to the folder containing mysql.exe, mysqldump.exe etc. (This example relies on having MySQL Workbench installed and just modify the path to your choise.

```
setx path "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE"
```